# About the $\lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)}{1+|f(x)|}$

Tags: calculus

So If for some function $f$,
$$\lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)}{1+|f(x)|} = k,$$

then $k\le 1$?

So what I've done is:

I've already proven that if $f(x)\le g(x)$ and their limits exists, then:
$$\lim_{x\to a}f(x) \le \lim_{x\to a}g(x)$$

Then I used this result to do something like this:

I know that:

$$\frac{f(x)}{1+|f(x)|} \le \frac{f(x)}{|f(x)|}$$ so:

$$\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)}{1+|f(x)|} \le \lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)}{|f(x)|}$$

Then, the limit of the right side of the inequation, is $1$ for $a>0$, $-1$ for $a<0$ and inconclusive if $a=0$. Then:

$$\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)}{1+|f(x)|} \le 1 = k$$

in the worst case. But I can't say this when $a=0$, and the exercise does not say anything about the $a$. Also: is my logic correct?

Thanks :)

Comment: This is wrong: "the limit of the right side of the inequation, is 1 for a>0, −1 for a<0 and inconclusive if a=0" It depends on the sign of $f(x)$ not on $a$

Comment: @Hamid could you please explain why? Thanks.

Comment: because for example $\frac{f(x)}{|f(x)|}$ is 1 if $f(x)>0$, not $a>0$

Comment: @Hamid thanks, this makes sense!

Answer (score 1):

You're making it overly complicated by setting $g(x) = f(x) / |f(x)|$.  Set $g(x) = 1$ instead.  $|f(x)| + 1$ is  always positive, and since $f(x) < 1+|f(x)|$,

$$\frac{f(x)}{1+|f(x)|} \le 1$$

To critique what you already have, as the comments mention, for the case when $f(x) = x$,

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{|f(x)|}$$

does not exist.  So the proof as you currently have it, is incorrect (since you can't satisfy the hypotheses for the theorem you're using).

Comment: Is it possible to $\frac{f(x)}{1+|f(x)|}$ be $=1$? I understood your answer.

Comment: So, I'm wrong because for $a\to 0$ there's no conclusion, so I can't say that the right side limit is always less than 1, right?

Comment: @MarterJs No it is not possible.  $f(x) < 1 + |f(x)|$.  However, it is possible for the limit to be $1$: take $f(x) = x$ and let $x \to +\infty$.  And to answer your second question, while the statement is correct and the left hand limit will be $\le 1$, your original proof was incorrect for the reason you state.

Comment: But my theorem says that na arbitrary $f(x)$ must be less or equal the right side, then the limit is less or equal 1, not only less than 1, like you did.

Comment: @MarterJs $f(x) < 1 + |f(x)|$ is stronger than $f(x) \le 1 + |f(x)|$.  It implies it.  If it's true (as it is), then the hypothesis of the implication is satisfied.